# White screen after build android

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Since I switched to cordova 12 I have had a problem when compiling on android. Smartphones below Android 10 display a white screen.
[image]

I tried to change the versions of target in the tsconfig but nothing.

Comment: What does you logcat or console say?

Comment: 2023-02-10 11:52:34.447 4500-4500/com.smartedafrica E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/natives_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/natives_blob_64.bin
2023-02-10 11:52:34.448 4500-4500/com.smartedafrica E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin

Comment: well there you go. theres an issue with an asset file.

Comment: Yes but I don't see which one

Comment: I created an empty ionic project and it's still stuck on white after the build.